# Finding Likely Causality of an Outlier

Tags: regression, outliers, causality, anomaly-detection

I have what I doubt is a new question in statistics but for some reason, maybe due to lack of vocabulary, I have not been able to find a good way to approach it.

I have some variable A that is dependent on a few other variables X, Y, Z, etc. When I find a simple outlier in A, something a few standard deviations away from the mean, I want to find which of the other variables was the likely cause of this outlier. For example if A is the age at which someone died and X was level of cholesterol, if A was unusually low I would want to see programatically that X was unusually high and a likely cause while the other variables were relatively the same. The variables X, Y, Z do not vary too much and could be modeled as gaussians.

I was thinking of doing some sort of regression to find relations and then compare each variable with A and see which fit the regression. In addition I thought of an even simpler method that may be too naive to just look for outliers in X, Y, Z for the same sample.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you describe are really outliers, but rather strongly predictive predictors.

I guess, if you were to center your predictive covariates (so that values away from zero in either direction are more unusual values), then extreme values of predictor times regression coefficient could be what you are looking for. You probably want to also take into account the standard error to account for variability or perhaps more easily in a Bayesian setting look at the distribution the posterior samples of the regression coefficients times covariate values. That would tell you which of the covariates is predicted to  lead to non-average outcomes. Of course, sometimes you just get somewhat extreme outcomes by chance or due to a combination of factors, and you cannot really conclude causality.

If A is the time to death, then you probably rather want some kind of time-to-event (aka survival analysis) rather than a linear regression, but the principle should be about the same.